# laravel get data from internal get request

Tags: php, laravel, get

My `billingController` returns this from `/billing/total`

`{"hours":23.25,"distances":209,"durations":3.5}`

I want to display this on a dashboard - called by the `homeController`

How get a make an internal get request to this data?

Comment: Use ajax for show this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should send `AJAX` call to that `URL`, get that data and parse it with `Javascript`.

If you still want to send request to that URL through another Laravel controller, you should use the following -

```
$request = Request::create('/billing/total', 'GET');

$response = Route::dispatch($request);
```

if it is `GET` request, or

```
$request = Request::create('/billing/total', 'POST');

$response = Route::dispatch($request);
```

if it is a `POST` request.

Comment: I can access the data like this, but it's clumsy: `echo $response->original['hours'];`

Comment: Try this way $response = json_decode(\Route::dispatch(\Request::create('/billing/total', 'GET'))->getContent());

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a blank request (body/query data) in any internal Laravel request, is due to `$request` actually referencing the current request (initiator) and not your newly created request (internal).

Take the example middle-ware below (fetching the entire body of the request):

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    // Works for external requests (string)
    // Blank for internal requests (null)
    $request->getContent();

    // Works for all requests (array)
    $request->post(); // array
}
```

As a pointer, for fetching single request elements you can use `$request->input('key')` (query/body), `$request->body('key')` (body) or `$request->query('key')` (query) to fetch. You'll encounter the same problems mentioned above with blank values, if you use the `Input` facade.